# How to let browser to download ByteArrayOutputStream to local in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm using Spring model.addAttribute to set the ByteArrayOutputStream value and send it to JSP . Please advise how to trigger the download option from JSP once that response JSP page loaded. I know how to do that by download file from server, But my idea is not to store anything in the server, instead do all using the ByteStream so that we can avoid IO throughput.

**Here is my controller class that will send the byte stream to JSP to display or download**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream fDoc = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fDoc = fileDownloader.geDownload(docID); //this will have the document stream
model.addAtrribute("doc",fDoc);
return "responseJSP"
```

Once the responseJSP loaded , I need to show the download option and let the user to download and save it as doc/docx in local .

Is there any other easy way I can render it in client side ?

Comment: If I got you correctly, you want to send the bytes to the client browser regardless if the user wants to download them or not? This will result in more I/O not less.

Comment: Hi , I want to trigger download option in JSP and store that Bytes that received from the model attribute to user local file as doc/docx .

Comment: You realize JSPs are rendered server-side (Java Server Pages), right? Passing data to the JSP doesn't get it any closer to the client. There's no magical way to avoid the IO cost of downloading a file.

Comment: But my question is how to let the jsp to show user download option in browser to download the ByteArrayOutputStream data .

Comment: the only way you have is to create a string with the file content and store it; when the client wants to download the file you must create a JS function that access to the string and create a file (using some file saver JS method). But... it's an approach i'd never use... you would create a very huge JSP and this means to stress the server

Comment: Possible to do it without store the content to a file ?